# Persisting web api access token at client side

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am working on an application which works with both the Web API and asp.net MVC. The Web API talks to the repositories and is in charge of authentication. The MVC application in turn is the endpoint for the client. I am using token-based authentication. To cut lots of things short, the clients use ajax to get their access tokens from the web api directly. Is it the right way to go about this?

Also, i want the users to log into the app directly like the implementation of a "Remember check box". I am thinking of storing the access token in a cookie to persist it. Is it a wise move? If not, what other options are available?

I've been searching online for some time. My major concern has been Cross Site Request Forgery(CSRF). Any inputs and all will be greatly appreciated.